# PHP cURL (Generated on Postman) not returning anything

Tags: php, curl

I've got this connection to an API that works perfect on Postman, it returns a Json showing what we just sent, in this example it returns {"id":9}.
However, when I use the cURL code generated by Postman it always returns nothing for the same data.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://us-central1-mitocondria-856e6.cloudfunctions.net/api/createUser",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"id\":9}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Bearer XXXX",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

The code above returns nothing.

`var_dump($response)` returns NULL
`var_dump($err)` returns string(0) ""
And `print_r(curl_getinfo($curl))` returns

```
Array ( [url] => https://us-central1-mitocondria-856e6.cloudfunctions.net/api/createUser/ [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0 [namelookup_time] => 0 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 0 [local_ip] => [local_port] => 0 )
```

I also changed the raw json data with `json_encode( array("id" => 8) )` and had the same outcome.
What else should I try? or there's an error I'm missing? Please help!

Comment: I've removed the token, good advise: don't post such sensitive data on public board.

Comment: Thanks Robert, my bad, was in a hurry and forgot to remove it

Comment: Could you try and set CURLOPT_VERBOSE and see what he does ?

Comment: @RăducanuIonuţ just tried it, it returns nothing, the log is empty

Comment: { "error" : "No autorizado." }, can you share a testing token ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupid error, and it had nothing to do with the code.
One of the first things I checked was that PHP had cURL module installed, but I didn't notice that it was disabled on php.ini, so the error showed in the only log I didn't checked, apache error.log.
After the module was enabled it worked like a spell.
Thank you all that tried to help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

1- Please mind your ',' in the last parameter of the curl array.

2- Please try and add

`CURLOPT_POST=> 1, // Means you have post data
 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $curl_data`'

Comment: The last ',' has nothing to do, it is a good practice with arrays

Comment: Ok. One more try from me. Hope it helps. Please try: `$ch =curl_init(" URL "); ` and then do : `curl_setopt_array($ch,array(......)); `

Comment: So, what i mean is, remove the url parameter from array() and pass it to `curl_init($url)`